# Restart an application with right permissions using system function?

Tags: c++, windows, batch-file, command-line

I'm trying to create the functionality of a program written in C++ to restart itself. In order to do that I create a batch file that kills the running process and starts it again. So when the program needs to restart, it calls the system function to start this .bat file.

It works great in my local testing environment but the production environment where this programa should run is a windows server 2012. In production environment when I execute the .bat file manually (double clicking the .bat file) it works great - the running program is killed and then started again. The problem is that when the program calls the system function to start the .bat, the process is killed fine but when it starts again a LOT of errors from the program arise (this programa works as a TCP server - which can't start to 'listen' in this case).

The code in the program to start the bat is the following:

```
system("restartGS.bat");
```

The contents of the bat is the following:

```
taskkill /F /IM GameServer.exe
START GameServer.exe
```

As suggested by @Gerhard Barnard in comments I tried removing taskkill's /F and start command, as follow (which gives the exact same problem):

```
taskkill /IM GameServer.exe && GameServer.exe
```

Is this a commom problem regarding the logic I'm using here? What could I do to try and fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just tested removing the /F parameter and using only taskkill and the exact problem persists. Any other idea? It seems to me to be some problem regarding user permissions. Why double-clicking the .bat it works just great and calling it from 'system' functin doesn't? Maybe 'system' does not give needed permission to the program?

Comment: You should provide a [mcve], without it, your question is off-topic. Also, you say you get errors, but completely omit what those are. Anyhow, here's a guess: `listen()` fails, because the hard kill of the program didn't properly close the according sockets. Only after a timeout of a minute (I believe that used to be the timeout) the TCP stack resets the connection state.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt What did I omit exactly? The errors from my program are not relevant to the question as I'm not asking for help to fix these errors. My question is about why when I execute the .bat file manually it works great and when I execute it from within the program through the `system` function it does not work. I don't think your guess about the `listen()` fail due to not closing prior socket is right because as I stated, when I execute the .bat file manually it works just fine.

Comment: @underthevoid: You're speculating whether the errors are relevant. Given that you can't solve the problem on your own, it's likely  at least one assumption is wrong. These rules aren't there to be annoying, it's to get good answers.

Comment: @underthevoid Errors from your program are the reason why you're asking this question, isn't it? Without them there wasn't an issue. Showing us which kind of errors you have could help to find a clue.